# How to send JsonObject in body for post request using rest assured?

Tags: json, gson, rest-assured

I have a JsonObject created using Google Gson.

```
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(response1_json, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
```

Also i made some modification to existing jsonobj as below :

```
JsonObject newObject = new JsonObject();
            newObject.addProperty("age", "50");
            newObject.addProperty("name", "X");
jsonObj.get("data").getAsJsonArray().add(newObject);
```

Now, using rest assured, i need to send the post request with this jsonobject. I tried the following but it doesn't work and throws exception:

```
Response postResponse = 
                    given()
            .cookie(apiTestSessionID)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(jsonObj.getAsString())
            .when()
            .post("/post/Config");
```

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: Try adding .contentType("application/json") instead of setting it as header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code to send Json to a Post request using Rest-assured

```
//Get jsonObject from response
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(response1_json, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();


//Create new jsonObject and add some properties
JsonObject newObject = new JsonObject();
    newObject.addProperty("age", "50");
    newObject.addProperty("name", "X");

//Get jsonarray from jsonObject
JsonArray jArr = jsonObj.get("data").getAsJsonArray();

//Add new Object to array
jArr.add(newObject);

//Update new array back to jsonObject
jsonObj.add("data", jArr);

Response postResponse = 
                given()
        .cookie(apiTestSessionID)
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(jsonObj.toString())
        .when()
        .post("/post/Config");
```

Comment: It works for me thanks.. I used contentType(applicaiton/json), which resolve my problem.